# loading the order number in an alert box from the database after the form is submitted

Tags: javascript, php, database, alert, data-retrieval

I am able to return a successful alert box message that my form is submitted successfully! Now i want to return the alert box with the message "Order placed successfully!Your order number is"+order number , by retrieving it from my database!
The following code written in the php script gives the alert following alert box

```
echo "<script>
alert('Order placed successfully!');

</script>";
```

[image]

The code to display the order number in the alert box is as follows

```
 $mysql="SELECT OrderNo. FROM `order` ";
    $results=mysqli_query($db,$mysql);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($results))
{
    echo "<script>
alert('Order placed successfully! your order number is";
        echo $row["OrderNo."];

        echo"');

</script>";
```

but after etering this code i get an error message of "syntax error, unexpected end of file in H:\xampnew\htdocs\project1\Test\Tests\orders_action.php on line 108"

please help me to rectify this error and correct it so that i can return the order number in the alert box which is retrieved from my database table named order!

Comment: So what's on line 108? You didn't split echo's over several lines like that, did you ?

Comment: the ending tags "?>" of the php script

Comment: So you've forgotten to close something then

Comment: nothings forgotten

Comment: So you've made that error on purpose? Me thinks you've forgotton something in your code, hence PHP thinks it's too early to close the script.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $mysql="SELECT OrderNo. FROM `order` ";
 $results=mysqli_query($db,$mysql);

 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>" .
        "alert('Order placed successfully! Your order number is " .
        $row['OrderNo.'] .
        " ');" .
        "</script>";
 }
```

Comment: still the problem is there :(

Comment: Adaneo is correct in his comment above, in that if the error line is pointing to the end of the PHP script then somewhere in your 108 lines of code you are missing a closing tag.

Comment: Proper formatting of your code and the use of a code editor or IDE will make it easier to locate syntax errors.